# exception with jedis pool using spring framework

Tags: spring, redis, jedis

I am trying to use jedis with spring framework (container: tomcat 7 on ubuntu running on windows VM) but keep getting the exception copied below (this setup works for me on another computer).  Redis is running on the server (process is up and listening on 0.0.0.0:6379).  This host/port is specified in my properties file.  I can add more information on the trace but it appears the error is due to the redis connection (jedis v 2.1.0, redis: 2.6.14 )

```
   Error creating bean with name 'jedisPool' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

**pom.xml file**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**applicationContext.xml file:**

```
<bean id="jedisPool" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean factory-bean="config" factory-method="getConfig" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${redis.host}" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="${redis.port}" />
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="${redis.timeout:5000}" />
</bean>
```

Any suggestions to troubleshoot this would be quite welcome.  I will check if its related to the jedis version as well.

Issue is most likely with my local setup - will update!

Comment: post the stacktrace of the error, and a bigger piece of your context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like a connection problem but a Spring configuration one. Perhaps the config parameter is wrong (e.g. wrong type).

In any case an option would be to rely on [spring-data-redis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis), in order to be more client implementation agnostic. It'd be fairly [simple to setup](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/).

Comment: thank you - it was a spring config issue - I did not get a chance to accept in the past.

Comment: @alihaider - Can you tell me what did you do? I am facing the same problem as you did. Would you please pass on the spring config code to me? thanks.

Comment: unfortunately do not have the project handy - I recall it was a spring config issue that I had incorrectly configured (make sure that you have the dependency configured correctly e.g. name/version and it is indeed getting pulled from whichever repo (local/remote) that you are pointing to in your pom file).

Comment: missing jdis in deps<dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring data Redis for it.
Below are the steps

1) make your maven pom.xml with following jars

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
               <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
               <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
               <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

2) make your configuration xml as follows

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">



    <bean id="jeidsConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      p:host-name="localhost" p:port="6379" p:password="" />

     <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
      p:connection-factory-ref="jeidsConnectionFactory" />

     <bean id="imageRepository" class="com.self.common.api.poc.ImageRepository">
      <property name="redisTemplate" ref="redisTemplate"/>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

3) Make your classes as follows

```
package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class RedisMainApp {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml");
  ImageRepository imageRepository = (ImageRepository) applicationContext.getBean("imageRepository");

  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("files/img/TestImage.png"));
  BufferedImage newImg;
  String imagestr;
  imagestr = encodeToString(img, "png");
  Image image1 = new Image("1", imagestr);

  img = ImageIO.read(new File("files/img/TestImage2.png"));
  imagestr = encodeToString(img, "png");
  Image image2 = new Image("2", imagestr);

  imageRepository.put(image1);
  System.out.println(" Step 1 output : " + imageRepository.getObjects());
  imageRepository.put(image2);
  System.out.println(" Step 2 output : " + imageRepository.getObjects());
  imageRepository.delete(image1);
  System.out.println(" Step 3 output : " + imageRepository.getObjects());

 }

 /**
  * Decode string to image
  * @param imageString The string to decode
  * @return decoded image
  */
 public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

     BufferedImage image = null;
     byte[] imageByte;
     try {
         BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
         imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
         ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
         image = ImageIO.read(bis);
         bis.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return image;
 }

 /**
  * Encode image to string
  * @param image The image to encode
  * @param type jpeg, bmp, ...
  * @return encoded string
  */
 public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
     String imageString = null;
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     try {
         ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
         byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

         BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
         imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

         bos.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return imageString;
 }
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

public class Image implements DomainObject {

 public static final String OBJECT_KEY = "IMAGE";

 public Image() {
 }

 public Image(String imageId, String imageAsStringBase64){
  this.imageId = imageId;
  this.imageAsStringBase64 = imageAsStringBase64;
 }
 private String imageId;
 private String imageAsStringBase64;

 public String getImageId() {
  return imageId;
 }

 public void setImageId(String imageId) {
  this.imageId = imageId;
 }

 public String getImageName() {
  return imageAsStringBase64;
 }

 public void setImageName(String imageAsStringBase64) {
  this.imageAsStringBase64 = imageAsStringBase64;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "User [id=" + imageAsStringBase64 + ", imageAsBase64String=" + imageAsStringBase64 + "]";
 }

 @Override
 public String getKey() {
  return getImageId();
 }

 @Override
 public String getObjectKey() {
  return OBJECT_KEY;
 }
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface DomainObject extends Serializable {

 String getKey();

 String getObjectKey();
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.util.List;

import com.self.common.api.poc.DomainObject;

public interface Repository<V extends DomainObject> {

 void put(V obj);

 V get(V key);

 void delete(V key);

 List<V> getObjects();
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;

import com.self.common.api.poc.DomainObject;

public class ImageRepository implements Repository<Image>{

 @Autowired
 private RedisTemplate<String,Image> redisTemplate;

 public RedisTemplate<String,Image> getRedisTemplate() {
  return redisTemplate;
 }

 public void setRedisTemplate(RedisTemplate<String,Image> redisTemplate) {
  this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
 }

 @Override
 public void put(Image image) {
  redisTemplate.opsForHash()
    .put(image.getObjectKey(), image.getKey(), image);
 }

 @Override
 public void delete(Image key) {
  redisTemplate.opsForHash().delete(key.getObjectKey(), key.getKey());
 }

 @Override
 public Image get(Image key) {
  return (Image) redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(key.getObjectKey(),
    key.getKey());
 }

 @Override
 public List<Image> getObjects() {
  List<Image> users = new ArrayList<Image>();
  for (Object user : redisTemplate.opsForHash().values(Image.OBJECT_KEY) ){
   users.add((Image) user);
  }
  return users;
 }

}
```

For more reference on sprinf jedis you can see http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/using-redis-with-spring.html

Sample Code is taken from http://javakart.blogspot.in/2012/12/spring-data-redis-hello-world-example.html

Comment: I don't know, but using spring data Redis seems ore complex. Jedis itself is pretty straight forward and clean to implement